# What are the Azure ML output formats?

Tags: azure, amazon-redshift, forecasting, azure-machine-learning-service

Does Azure ML only provide output through it's web services? 
Is it possible to feed the output to an Azure SQL database? 
Is it possible to feed the output to a Redshift database?

Essentially I am looking to know if I can integrate Azure ML Studio with our existing redshift analytics database.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can write to SQL DB in Azure. 
you can also use a Python module to make REST calls so in theory you can write to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to SQL DB is possible in Azure ML and so is Writing directly to Azure Blob Storage.

However, unlike @Hai, I do not believe you can write to a Redshift DB since it is clearly stated by the "Python Module" documentation from Microsoft that the Python execution is Sandboxed and therefore can not access resources outside the virtual machine it runs on(i.e Internet resources, on-premises resources, ...)